# Is there a name for a region of a circle comprising an inscribed angle subtending a chord, and a corresponding circular segment? ("ice-cream cone"?)

Tags: terminology, circles

Is there a name for the particular part of a circle shown in red? I know the white sections are segments. If the vertex was at the center of the circle it would be a sector.

I don't suppose that any mathematician would have been brazen enough to call it the "ice-cream cone."

[image]

Comment: I vote in favour of "ice cream cone".

Comment: Well a sector could be a slice of pizza relative to the pie, this could be the slice once on a plate.

Comment: More seriously, but still clunky, a [segment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) plus a triangle. By the way are the sides guaranteed to be the same length? If not, it wouldn't be an ice cream cone. Also, oh my god not the new title :D

Comment: No the sides of the triangle wouldn't necessarily be equal. "ice-cream cone" was tongue in cheek of course.